# Identity Server 4 AddOidcStateDataFormatterCache does not apply to AddGoogle

Tags: identityserver4

When using the AddOidcStateDataFormatterCache method via:

```
services.AddOidcStateDataFormatterCache();
```

It only applies to providers which are added using

```
.AddOpenIdConnect();
```

Is there a way to apply the distributedCacheFormatter when using

```
.AddGoogle()
```

Google is also an OpenId Provider and can be added using .AddOpenIdConnect or .AddGoogle, but using .AddGoogle doesn't use the state data formatter. I confirmed this by checking the redis cache (used as the underlying implementation of IDistributedCache) and saw a key created "DistributedCacheStateDataFormatter..." when using .AddOpenIdConnect, but nothing is created when using .AddGoogle.

I'm thinking this might be because .AddGoogle might use a different authentication handler which doesn't get picked up automatically by AddOidcStateDataFormatterCache

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the `GoogleOptions` class inherits from `OAuthOptions` and not `OpenIdConnectOptions` but they both have a `ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationProperties> StateDataFormat` so you could re-use the `DistributedCacheStateDataFormatter` provided by `identityserver4`

The post-configure class:

```
internal class ConfigureGoogleOptions : IPostConfigureOptions<GoogleOptions>
{
    private string[] _schemes;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public ConfigureGoogleOptions(string[] schemes, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _schemes = schemes ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(schemes));
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContextAccessor));
    }

    public void PostConfigure(string name, GoogleOptions options)
    {
        // no schemes means configure them all
        if (_schemes.Length == 0 || _schemes.Contains(name))
        {
            options.StateDataFormat = new DistributedCacheStateDataFormatter(_httpContextAccessor, name);
        }
    }
}
```

And the registration helper (add this to your own static class):

```
public static IServiceCollection AddGoogleStateDataFormatterCache(this IServiceCollection services, params string[] schemes)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IPostConfigureOptions<GoogleOptions>>(
        svcs => new ConfigureGoogleOptions(
            schemes,
            svcs.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>())
    );
    return services;
}
```

Comment: This was really helpful! Thanks!